# What is the main advantage of using SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, webview, safari, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am not getting proper understanding of what is the main adavantage of using SFSafariViewController, if we are using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl: strUrl];`

What are the difference between both?

Comment: You can add delegate to SFSafariViewController that will handle Actions. Also, I think that main advantage that user stays in the application while he look at data in the Internet.

Comment: In case of [UIApplication openURL:], Safari is launched and your app is no longer in foreground and, generally, is not guaranteed to be running. In contrast, SFSafariViewController is a part of your app and you retain some control over it as a UIViewController or with SFSafariViewControllerDelegate methods. Which one to use depends on what you want to achieve. There is also WKWebView which gives you more control over the content and navigation but lacks some features of Safari such as content blocking.

Comment: if you use `SFSafariViewController`, your application will remain the active app in foreground; if you open _Safari_ app, your app will become inactive and goes to background.

Comment: Thanks for sharing info... :)

Comment: @Baglan that's valuable information. I was thinking of copy/pasting your answer into an answer, but it would be better if you do it yourself. Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @Honey, I'm glad you've found my comment useful. I thought that it was just a little too cursory to warrant posting it as an answer. I've done that now!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With SFSafariViewController, you can use nearly all of the benefits of viewing web content inside Safari without forcing users to leave your app.

The majority of apps just need to provide a generalized web viewing experience. This is the perfect scenario for the safari view controller.

Before SFSafariViewController, the browsing experience was inconsistent across different apps, which may confuse the user. Some interfaces may also lack the things users expect, such as a progress bar indicating how much of the page is loaded. You don't have access to all of Safari's features. This includes the reader view, the iCloud keychain for autofill capabilities, and more.

If you wanted to have those features before iOS 9, you were forced to have the user leave your app entirely by opening the content inside Safari. `SFSafariViewController` solves every one of these problems.

For more see [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260)

Answer (score 2):

In case of [UIApplication openURL:], Safari is launched and your app is no longer in foreground and, generally, is not guaranteed to be running. In contrast, SFSafariViewController is a part of your app and you retain some control over it as a UIViewController or with SFSafariViewControllerDelegate methods. Which one to use depends on what you want to achieve. There is also WKWebView which gives you more control over the content and navigation but lacks some features of Safari such as content blocking.